# How to make a BASH script work only in a specific directory?

Tags: linux, bash, conditional-statements

my Linux homework requires that I write a script that only runs if the user is in ~/tareas/sesion_3, so I assume he first needs to input cd /~/tareas/sesion_3 and then the script commands will run, if not it'll echo "you're not on /~/tareas/sesion_3". In the script I need to make more directories, and they can only be created in that location.

**How can I make such condition?**

I appreciate every bit of help you guys can offer!

Comment: Does it also need to work if inside of a _child_ directory of the given directory? For instance, `/tareas/sesion_3/bin` ?

Comment: Is there a reason that your script can't switch to the necessary folder itself?

Comment: @Raceimazation - it is a homework question, which often tasks students with doing things to gain understanding (not always resulting in a sensible program).

Answer (score 5):

You can use `$PWD` to see what parent directory the script was run from, although it will have expanded `~` already. So you can do something like:

```
if [[ "$PWD" == "/home/tareas/session_3" ]]; then
  # do stuff if true
else
  # do stuff if false
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

my answer is:

```
#!/bin/sh

TARGET_DIR = "~/tareas/sesion_3" 

function do_something(){
    #do something
}

function do_something_v2(){
    #create some dirs
}

if [ `pwd` == "$TARGET_DIR" ] ; then
    do_something
else 
    do_something_v2
```

i hope it can help you

^_^

Comment: This script doesn't work because `pwd` uses the full pathname so it will not match your `~`.  Also, two comments for improvement. 1) Use the `$PWD` environment variable instead of calling the external command `pwd` 2) If you are going to try to keep it POSIX by using `sh` instead of `bash` then you should *not* use `==` but rather `=` when comparing strings with `test`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to see if you are at least *inside* of the given directory, but perhaps in a child directory therein, `grep` is a good friend to have:

```
echo `pwd` | grep ^/starting/directory >/dev/null || {
       echo "You aren't in the proper place .."
       exit 1
}
```

Example of it working:

```
tpost@tpost-desktop:~$ echo `pwd` | grep ^/home/tpost >/dev/null || echo nope
tpost@tpost-desktop:~$ echo `pwd` | grep ^/home/foo >/dev/null || echo nope
nope
```

The carat (`^`) tells grep to match a line that *starts with* what you provide.

Comment: This can be done with shell syntax without the need to call two external binaries, `pwd` and `grep`. Just use `*` as in `if [[ $PWD/ == /home/tpost/* ]]`

Comment: Why "echo $(pwd)"?  Just invoke pwd directly.  i.e. "pwd | grep ... ".  (note: backticks aren't showing up in the comment, so I've replaced them with $())

Comment: @William just backslash escape the first backtick like so: \`echo`